# add library occurred build errors

Tags: android, android-studio

What went wrong?

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.> 
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android programs are compiled into .dex (Dalvik Executable) files, which are in turn zipped into a single .apk file on the device. Sometimes, You need to enable multidex support & larger heap size for compiling those classes with large dex size. For this do the following changes,

First of all, add the multidex dependencies in **build.gradle**,

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

change the **dexOptions**,

```
android {
dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
```

Lastly, add a singleton class that extends multidex support,

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

Open your manifest file and add the singleton class,

```
<application
        android:name=".app.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        .....
   </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

add below in your build gradle:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

add multiDexEnabled true in defaultconfig of build.gradle like this

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```